# Table with position: fixed doesn't scroll with overflow: scroll

Tags: html, css

I have two tables: the first is a header, the second contains data. I want to see the header when I scroll down, so its table has `position: fixed`. The tables can be too large to be shown on the screen at once, so I wrapped them in a div with `overflow: scroll;`.

My problem can be see here: https://jsfiddle.net/xa86wgw9/3/

When I scroll down, the header doesn't move; that's what I want. But when I scroll to the right, the header stay on the left... is there a way to have the two table stay aligned ? css and javascript can be used.

EDIT: I'm currently working on IE10, so `position: sticky` isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example. make sure window is having in a size with both scroll bars are visible.

I used two tables, one for header and another for content. The header is fixed positioned. when you scroll horizontally, its left offset is changing accordingly.

sorry for the rough styles and lengthy markup!

```js
$(window).scroll(function (){
     var scrollxValue = $(window).scrollLeft();
     $('.vertically-fixed').css('left', -scrollxValue)
});
```

```css
table{
                width: 2120px;
            }
            .vertically-fixed{
                position: fixed;
                height: 40px;
            }
            th,td{
                padding: 5px 10px;
                margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
                width: 110px;
                height: 110px;
                float: left;
            }
            th{
                background: #ddd;
            }
            td{
                background: #eee;
            }
            tbody {
                height: 100px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="vertically-fixed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>dolor</th>
                    <th>cursus</th>
                    <th>tincidunt</th>
                    <th>porttitor</th>
                    <th>Maecenas</th>
                    <th>Fusce tincidunt</th>
                    <th>Vivamus</th>
                    <th>Lorem ipsum</th>
                    <th>dolor</th>
                    <th>cursus</th>
                    <th>tincidunt</th>
                    <th>porttitor</th>
                    <th>Maecenas</th>
                    <th>Fusce tincidunt</th>
                    <th>Vivamus</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        
        <table class="content">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>03</td>
                    <td>04</td>
                    <td>05</td>
                    <td>06</td>
                    <td>07</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: I had to adjust the margin-top of the second table, but it works !

Comment: yeh! It was overlapping the content.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not necessary** to use **2 tables** to achieve what you want.It is possible by **1 table code** itself.

Fiddle created here to test the scrolling of the body section and keeping the header fixed
http://jsfiddle.net/pxgq1j4p/

You need to use

```
<thead>
<tbody>
```

Comment: @gobes need a horizontal scroll also in which header should scroll along the content.

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman If I wrap the table in a div, I can achieve what I want, but it seems a bit ugly to me...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its impossible to make the table itself scrollable.

As your second table also uses the scrolloptions of #firstDiv, you need to do the same for the first one, since the first one is fixed and so not counted inside the #firstDiv for width properties.

to achieve this I added a wrapperdiv around the first table and made the wrapper fixed with

```
overflow: scroll;
```

EDIT:
See the fiddle: - sry forgot to update the link, here you go
https://jsfiddle.net/xa86wgw9/8/

for the second part of your question you probably need some javascript to make both tables scroll at the same time. but you should try this part yourself first (also I lack time to apply the solution now)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:sticky`to achieve what you want

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa86wgw9/7/)**

Comment: it's not fully supported, for example as fr as I know it's not working on IE, ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: Afortunately some of us can ignore IE or edge when designing our webs. This is after all an effect he want to achieve, ie users can just simple scroll all table down.

Comment: works fine for chrome, but in case of tables not even supported for Firefox